# Catch Javascript fetch failing with Cloudflare 429 missing CORS header

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, cloudflare

I am using Fetch to make **cross origin requests** in javascript.

Cloudflare (proxying my traffic) will sometimes return a 429 (rate limiting).

When they return 429, they do not include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

So now my `fetch` with `mode: 'cors'` fails, and throws a `TypeError`

How can I catch when this happens, vs. when it throws for other reasons like network errors?

[image: screenshot]

My code is as follows:

```
    try {
        let response = await fetch(uri, config); // this throws
        if (!response.ok) { // this line does not run
            throw response.statusText;
        }
        let json = await response.json();
        return json;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message); // "Failed to fetch"
    }
```

Checking [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful), I'm not sure if it's possible to detect this 429 separate from other network errors?

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar

[image: response]

Comment: Are you using "fetch-interceptor" or a similar library, and handling these requests elsewhere in the code (globally)?

Comment: @MattU - Nope, I'm not using anything like that

Comment: Strange. I follow this exact same pattern with fetch and Vue, and I have no issues. Is there any way you could reproduce the issue on CodePen or StackBlitz or similar, and share it here?

Comment: @MattU it might have something to do with it being CORS going through cloudflare? I've added a screenshot of the response.

Comment: How are you dealing with CORS? What do you have on your `config`?

Comment: `{mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include'}` if that's what you're asking for?

Comment: The server you’re making the requests to must be reconfigured to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 4xx errors. The response headers shown in the question don’t include that header; so if this is a cross-origin request, the browser blocks your frontend code from accessing the response — including status. Check the devtools console and you’ll see the browser is logging a CORS error there. Most servers by default don’t add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 4xx errors — instead it’ll only get added to 2xx success responses. Lacking that, browsers won’t let you access the status.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker I just realized this and updated the question with more context if you have any other ideas on how to figure this out!

Comment: The only way you could work around this from just your frontend JavaScript code is to add some kind of throttling so that you don’t hit whatever rate limiting is causing you to get those 429 errors to begin with. Otherwise, there’s no way to work around it in just your frontend code. So either you’ll need to use a CORS proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, or instead make the request from your server-side backend code (because there’s no same-origin restrictions there), or else try to get Cloudlflare to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 429 responses.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is you can't, and this is by design.

The only place where this could be fixed is the server-side. Either Cloudflare needs to be changed/configured to send the appropriate headers or using a different service that does send the headers on error.

Without a server-side change, the error will be a generic CORS error.

The other alternative might to do build something like an 'iframe proxy', effectively letting you circumvent CORS entirely.

Answer (score -1):

status code: 429 is returned when user sends too many requests in given time.
that means eventListners are making multiple requests(thats what I think).

So, to stop eventListners from making multiple requests use

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

If several listeners are attached to the same element for the same event type, they are called in the order in which they were added. If stopImmediatePropagation() is invoked during one such call, no remaining listeners will be called.

read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) MDN docs.